# Spring Kafka Transaction - Duplicate messages published to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-transactions, spring-kafka

We are trying to implement transaction for our producer. Our use case we receive the message from MQ and published to kafka. When there is a failure, we need to rollback the message published to kafka and don't send an acknowledgment to MQ.

We see messages are duplicated in kafka topic when we use transaction.

```
@Bean("producerConfig")
public Properties producerConfig() {
    LOGGER.info("Creating Dev Producer Configs");
    Properties configs = new Properties();
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, localhost:9092);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 1);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
    return configs;
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(new HashMap<String, Object>((Map) producerConfig));
    producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("spring-kafka-transaction");
    return producerFactory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(topic);
    return kafkaTemplate;
}


@Bean
KafkaTransactionManager<String,String> kafkaTransactionManager(){
    KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> transactionManager = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Listener method

```
@Component
public class WMQListener implements MessageListener {

KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

@Override
@Transactional
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    String onHandXmlStr = null;
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            onHandXmlStr = textMessage.getText();
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Message Received from WMQ :: " + onHandXmlStr);
        Msg msg = JaxbUtil.convertStringToMsg(onHandXmlStr);
        List<String> onHandList = DCMUtil.convertMsgToList(msg);

        ListenableFuture send = kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(onHandList.get(0));
        send.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object result) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        });
     message.acknowledge();

}
```

Comment: Do you have `@EnableTransactionManagement` on one of your `@Configuration` classes? Have you changed your consumer `ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG` to `READ_COMMITTED` ? If yes to both, does a DEBUG log (for `org.apache.kafka`, `org.springframework.transaction`) help you understand what's going on?

Comment: Yes, I have `@EnableTransactionManagement` but I am currently testing producer application and have not started a consumer, Since I observed offset is incremented by two for a single message I have a concern. Today I have tested by starting a console consumer on the same topic without specifying `READ COMMITTED` explicitly but I received only on message and not the duplicate. However, I am wondering why offset is increased by two when I use `@Transaction` and `KafkaTransactionManager` and not happening without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I am wondering why offset is increased by two

Since kafka topics are a linear log (per partition), rolled-back messages still take up a slot in the log (guess).

Consider this...

- p1.send(tx) (offset 23)
- p2.send(tx) (offset 24)
- p1.rollback
- p2.commit
- p1.resend(tx) (offset 25).
- p1.commit.

My guess is that p1's record at offset 23 is simply marked as rolled back and not sent to consumers (unless active at the time it was written with read_uncommitted isolation).

**EDIT**

I see no difference in offsets with/without transactions

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So48196671Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(So48196671Application.class, args);
        Thread.sleep(15_000);
        ctx.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> foo.send("bar");
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> transactionManager(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "so48196671")
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset) {
        System.out.println(in + " @ " + offset) ;
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Autowired
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

        @Transactional
        public void send(String out) throws Exception {
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sent = template.send("so48196671", out);
            SendResult<String, String> sendResult = sent.get();
            System.out.println(out + " sent to " + sendResult.getRecordMetadata().offset());
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
bar sent to 17
bar @ 17
```

But, yes, with a failure scenario, an extra slot is used...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So48196671Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(So48196671Application.class, args);
        Thread.sleep(15_000);
        ctx.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                foo.send("bar");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //
            }
            foo.send("bar");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> transactionManager(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "so48196671")
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset) {
        System.out.println(in + " @ " + offset) ;
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        private boolean fail = true;

        @Autowired
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

        @Transactional
        public void send(String out) throws Exception {
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sent = template.send("so48196671", out);
            SendResult<String, String> sendResult = sent.get();
            System.out.println(out + " sent to " + sendResult.getRecordMetadata().offset());
            if (fail) {
                fail = false;
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
bar sent to 25
bar sent to 27
bar @ 27
```

and on the next run...

```
bar sent to 29
bar sent to 31
bar @ 31
```

If I delete the exception, on the next run, I get

```
bar sent to 33
bar sent to 35
bar @ 33
bar @ 35
```

So, yes, it appears that the transaction itself takes up a slot in the log.

So it's not really a duplicate message - you can probably read about it in their design docs.

Comment: Yes, This holds true if there is any failure and an operation is rolled back, But in normal scenarios, it should not rollback a transaction and offset should not be increased by two.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean, with an example and logs.

Comment: Excuse me if I am not able to provide enough details or explain well, I am sending a single message without `@Transactional` and `KafkaTransactionManager`
using `kafkaTemplate.send()` I get my offset incremented by one

Comment: Now I have added `@Transactional` to my listener and send again a single message
In this case, offset is incremented by two, But I don't have any transaction rollback or any type of failure
I understand if I am sending a message like you have explained
p1.send(tx)(offset 23)
In this case, I should get offset as 23 but when I see offset it is increased to 24. Since there isn't any failure no rollback should happen

Comment: Also, I observed that my consumer is receiving only one message. However, log offset is incremented by two and I always see a lag of one message even though my consumer is up and running.  I am using read_committed in my consumer.

Comment: See my edit; it appears that the transaction uses up a slot in the log.

Comment: Yes, I'll look for their design document. Meanwhile, I have also posted to a confluent group, As extra consumer lag for each transaction creates a confusion whether that lag is about a transaction or its real consumer is lagging.

Comment: I have just got a response on this, and yes the transaction itself takes up a slot in the log [google group response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/confluent-platform/IQKd3BKgvYw/4gjtrcfgEQAJ)

Comment: But still, I am wondering about showing an extra consumer lag, Would explore it.